# Can't import plotly.figure_factory

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

I'm not being able to import `plotly.figure_factory`

The code I use is based on [this example](https://plot.ly/python/candlestick-charts/)

The module is imported by the following snippet:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.figure_factory as FF
```

I couldn't find any documentation on `figure_factory` in `plotly`'s website.

Any ideas ?

Comment: You'd think one of the top 5 tutorials they show here would have this update taken into account... https://plot.ly/python/ The jupyter notebook one has this error

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Plotly's documentation is sometimes a bit inconsistent and missed some updates to the library itself.

If you substitute your second line with

```
from plotly.tools import FigureFactory as FF
```

your code should work as expected.

Comment: Actually, `plotly.tools.FigureFactory.create_trisurf` seems to have been deprecated. I was told use `plotly.figure_factory.create_trisurf` instead. And it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is the version problem.
I used jupiter notebook on google colab, and:

```
import plotly.figure_factory as FF
```

wouldn't work, because the plotly is 1.1.12

But if you try

```
from plotly.tools import FigureFactory as FF
```

it works.

Check the version using:

```
import plotly
print (plotly.\_\_version\_\_)
```